# WinRT Windows 10. Launch Website without opening metro app

Tags: windows-runtime, cortana

I'm currently trying to write a code that utilizes Cortana's Speech Recognition. I want to create a command that launch website for e.g "Mark, Open google page" Mark is the AppName declared in the VCD.  I'm currently using:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://google.com"));
```

But the documentation for LauncUriAsync() states that "The calling app must be visible to the user when the API is invoked." Is there an equivalent API i can use that doesn't need the calling app to be visible?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this restriction, but you could just add a part of your own app that uses the WebView control to preview the content, and if someone wants to do more, provide a button in your app that then launches the user's browser if they need a fully-featured browser. Not ideal, but may well do the job for basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but,I want it to be in the background since we want to use cortana to launch websites we often use using commands. We're not really building a full blown application