# Open a link in browser after clicking cortana tile

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-rt, cortana, background-application

- I have developed a universal app which displays sharepoint files in
  cortana canvas in the form of tiles. So, when one clicks on the tile,
  it launches the app in foreground which then opens a link in browser
  and then  the app closes.
- I want to hide the app from being shown to the user. It is desirable
  that when one clicks the tile it directly opens the link in the
  browser.

Comment: What you mean by "displays sharepoint files in cortana canvas in the form of tiles"? Is this "tile" your application's tile?

Comment: No I am retrieving the sharepoint files and then displaying it on cortana canvas

Comment: And what is the cortana canvas? You mean in the "Feedback" interface display a sharepoint file? And this file should be opened by browser? Anyway, I just tried it, I can't hide the app.

Comment: Can a Cortana background Task open the Browser? Or is it restricted?
I just found the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289835/winrt-windows-10-launch-website-without-opening-metro-app
The App has to be launched in the foreground.

Comment: Currently on clicking the tile I have opened the app to open the file in the browser and then closed the app.